# Azure Storage Download Expiry

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We have started to encounter the following 403 error message when some files are requested to be downloaded from Azure Storage:

[image]

The error seems to indicate that there is an issue with the server's clock being out of sync with the Azure Storage server - however - this isn't happening for every file that is downloaded, only some files and it is consistently failing for those files.

The issue is occurring from a server we host ourselves in a data center and also from a cloud-service hosted website.

We haven't deployed any new code recently to either environment.

Would greatly appreciate any insight into why this is occurring!

Comment: From the error it is pretty clear that the SAS URL you're using to download the file is expiring. Please try by increasing the expiry time of the SAS URL.

Comment: I agree but why would this not be consistent for all files?

Comment: Time to download the file depends on the size of the file. Bigger the size, more time it would take to download the file and more chances of SAS expiring in between the download process.

Comment: Turns out the issue isn't associated to file size, we are seeing a lot of latency from Azure so files that previously downloaded in a few seconds have been taking 10 seconds. Increasing the expiry time did fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @GauravMantri should post the solution as a proper answer, to make sure this question is closed appropriately (and with proper attribution for the answer :) ).